# Decoding an .iwa file

Tags: file-format, iwork, apple-numbers

I am looking to view the contents of an `.iwa` file in my Apple Numbers project. It seems like the format is a [protobuf wrapped in snappy](https://github.com/obriensp/iWorkFileFormat/blob/master/Docs/index.md#iwa). I was wondering if there was a relatively simple/crude way to view the text contents of the data. I tried with a basic `hexdump` but it just gives me some gibberish, probably because of the snappy encoding.

What might be a way to view this data? As an example, here is a sample file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-AZdpuoshfmpjxMfi7ARKhneeUNmW9Xx/view?usp=sharing

Comment: often there is some ISO spec describing all the minute details of an encoding ... I once had to ruffle through hundreds of pages of such a spec to write code to parse a compressed binary http-live-streaming feed on an embedded project

Comment: Have your find an answer? I've faced the same problem.